# Exclude characters from search in Mysql

Tags: mysql, search

Is it possible to make some characters stored in mysql invisible for search queries?

Of course, I can do this in application, but is there maybe some setting option in mysql for this?

Comment: I do not understand your question. Could you explain in more detail?

Comment: For instance, I have string field where some values have "@" in it. Is it possible to tell mysql, that this character is invisible, if you search "... WHERE StringField='%@%'...". For me this would be sort off double safety.

Answer (score 1):

I am still not sure I am following what you want. It sounds like a query like

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE REPLACE(string_field, "@", "") = "user query"
```

might be what you are looking for.

See [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace). For more complicated matching, there's also [regular expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp), although that would probably be rather messy for what you are describing.

**EDIT:** Just saw your comment. It sounds like you want to blacklist certain characters from the user's query as they are special to your system. No, there's no way to do that. Somewhere you are going to want a string replace operation to remove those characters; either in your application or in a stored procedure/function if you want to put it in the database.

Comment: Ah, stored procedure would solve the problem, because I need in database level. Thx